# C++ Sorting problem

Tags: c++

I want to create a sorting system, it gets some numbers and sort it DESC.

if I enter `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` (orderly), that code works fine ..
but if enter that numbers, disorderly, it is broken down ..

my code is::

```
#include <iostream.h>
main () {
 int a[10], max, temp;
 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    cout << "Enter number " << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> a[i];
 }

 for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
  for (int x=0; x<=j; x++) {
    if (a[j] > a[j+1]) {
     temp = a[j];
     a[j] = a[j+1];
     a[j+1] = temp;
    }
  }
 }

 cout << "Sort [DESC]: \n";
 for (int w=9; w>=0; w--) {
    cout << w << ". " << a[w] << "\n";
 }
 //cout << "Max: " << max;
}
```

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Looks like a [traditional bubble sort](http://mathbits.com/mathbits/compsci/arrays/bubble.htm) from here.

Comment: You know you don't need to do that right? Unless this is for learning purposes only.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/greater/

Comment: It's `int main()`. The implicit int is no longer valid in C++.

Comment: This looks very homework-ish. If so we should tag it as such...

Comment: Use `<iostream>`. There is no `<iostream.h>` in the C++ standard and never was.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it very amusing that this algorithm only works for the expected output?

Comment: @Axel: Well, there was never an `<iostream.h>` in standard C++, but that doesn't mean it was not there in pre-standard C++.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: It works in my compiler .. I have an old compiler!! :D

Comment: @kikio: Just because it works on your compiler doesn't mean that it is good. There are plenty of free and extremely good compilers available (i.e. MSVC++, G++, CLang, etc.). There's no reason to continue to use antiquated compilers like Turbo C++ and friends.

Comment: @the_drow: Well... it is not the algorithm, but a bug in the implementation, take a look at the loop indices and the operations performed in the inner loop (that refer only to the outer loop control variable, with the inner loop variable never being used)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Well, the amusing thing is that he mentions that it works when it does nothing. But you are correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing `a[10]` (through `a[j+1]`), which surely can't be correct. Naive bubble sort would usually look like this, for instance:

```
for(int i = NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS - 1; i > 0; --i)
for(int t = 0; t < i; ++t)
{
    if(item [t] greater than [t+1])
    {
        swap item [t] with [t+1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't understand why `> 0` is your comparison -- typically it would be either comparing the left element with the right element, or it would be a strcmp style comparison function in which case you need `!= 0` not `> 0`.

Comment: @Billy: Changed that, it was just an example. In case of integers, it would be `item[t] > item[t+1]`, for strings it would be `strcmp(item[t], item[t+1]) > 0`, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create a sorting system

Already done for you as part of the standard library:

http://codepad.org/VBAB0JBo

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void PrintNumbers(int * myArray)
{
    std::copy(myArray, myArray + 10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int myArray[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    //Sort ascending
    std::sort(myArray, myArray + 10);
    PrintNumbers(myArray);
    //Sort descending
    std::sort(myArray, myArray + 10, std::greater<int>());
    PrintNumbers(myArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using C++ you can use STL [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) instead of array and then use STL algorithm [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Comment: `std::sort` is good advice. However, given that the array is stack allocated it's perfectly fine -- no reason to use a vector here.